# Cannot find element in page using selenium in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find an element [from this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jQzU.jpg) which is a button but I am unable to find the element. I have tried finding by `class_name`, `xpath`, `id` but none seems to work its showing
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:`

```html
<button class="dates_head commo_btn">
<!-- react-text: 175 -->
09
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 176 -->
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 177 -->
MON
<!-- /react-text -->
</button>
```

The xpath value is unique as it should be, but still, it is not able to find the element

I am using Python 3.7.2, selenium 3.141.0, chromedriver 2.40 on Fedora 29 
Any help on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To click on react element you need to induce **WebDriverWait** and **element_to_be_clickable()**

Use following xpath locator strategy.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='dates_head commo_btn'][contains(.,'09')][contains(.,'MON')]"))).click()
```

You need to **import** followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Please note if you still get `timeout error` then check if there any `iframe` available.

Comment: But the problem is with finding the element itself so click is only possible if the element is found first and aslo the page is loaded after that only i have tried to find the element

Comment: @Sandipan : You have provided very limited information to find out why No such element error is coming.However I have mentioned my answer please check if there any iframe as well?